# Illuminate\Support\Collection::filter(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be of type ?callable, array given, called in

Tags: php, laravel

I have query that i have cached forever

controller.php

```
$duplex = Cache::rememberForever('duplex', function () {
            return Property::where('buildingtype_id', '4')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->get();
        })
```

in view.php, i have added a filter in which users can filter down from the cached data to what they want.

in model.php

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
    {
        // search filter address
        $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, fn($query, $search) =>

            $query->where(fn($query) =>
                $query->where('address', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')

                )
        );}
```

So i want when a user search for certain strings, it will go through the address of cached data $duplex and filter it.
My idea is

```
$duplex->filter(request(['search']))->withQueryString();
```

But this gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing `Model::scopeFilter()` like you think you are. You are actually calling that model's [`Collection::filter()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-filter).

Let's start with the query:

```php
Property::where('buildingtype_id', '4')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This query will return your results in a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance. Your `$duplex` variable is not a `QueryBuilder::class` (this is what you think you are accessing) it is a `Collection::class`. If you don't understand this, then you need to read up on Laravel's eloquent models and query builder and scoping.

To fix it you'd have to inject the `search` value within the query `Property::where()->filter(request(['search'])->get()` or you'd need to filter the collection after the fact and use the `filter()` method correctly.

An updated query (accounting for the `cache()->rememberForever()`.

```php
$filter = request(['filter']);
$cacheKey = 'duplex';
if ($filter) {
    $cacheKey .= '-' . md5(serialize($filter));
}

$duplex = Cache::rememberForever($cacheKey, function () use ($filter) {
    return Property::query()
        ->where('buildingtype_id', '4')
        ->filter($filter)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
});
```

If you want filtering after the results have been fetched, you will be using the `Collection::filter()` method. You won't be able to use the `scopeFilter()` method at that point, but there's the [`stristr()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) you can call and get a similar result.

```php
$duplex = Cache::rememberForever('duplex', function () {
    return Property::where('buildingtype_id', '4')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
});

$filter = request(['search']);
$filtered = $duplex->when(
  ! empty($filter),
  fn ($d) => stristr($d->address, $filter) !== false
);
```

The second option is not optimal, it would be better to get rid of your `rememberForever` wrapper or ensure your cache key is based on search filters as I have in the first example.